# Нужна ли запятая?

Tags: пунктуация

Ув. филологи, подскажите, нужна ли запятая?
Думаете, почему он такое внимание ей уделяет?

Answer (score 3):

Запятая нужна, она отделяет вводное слово "думаете", служащее для привлечения внимания.